# Multiple singlethreaded servers or Multiple Multithreaded servers with Apache Thrift?

Tags: thrift

I am implementing a Microservices architecture using Apache Thrift. What is the recommended way to architect a group of services? I can think of 2 options:

1. Multithreaded server per service. Each server listening to one port.
2. Multiple Singlethreaded servers per service. Again, each server listening to one port.

Comment: Whatever fits your use case best.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which case fits each solution?